# How to render from a different column instead of the first column

Tags: react-data-grid

I've have a 50 column data-grid and i want to render a different column when component mounts. That means i want to render the data starting from another column.
Like in below image, rather than starting from 1, i want to start it from 14
[image]

I've gone through docs and found that i can do this by using colDisplayStart but not sure where to begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer by using refs

```
<ReactDataGrid
     ref="the_ref"
     //other options
 />
```

And the use the ref to scroll by using the function `scrollToColumn`

Example usage:

```
this.refs.the_ref.scrollToColumn(col_id);
```